# Error creating AWS MySQL RDS instance with Terraform

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

When creating an Amazon AWS RDS MySQL 5.7 db instance using Terraform "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws" module, I started getting a strange error after > 1 hour. In other contexts in the past the same script worked (even more involved versions creating cross-region read replica in 2 other regions (3 in total).

When I tried to deploy to a different VPC recently I started getting an error after spending ~1 hour on the db options group resource (so not even reaching db deploy).

The error message is:

```
aws_db_option_group.this: Error creating DB Option Group: InternalFailure: An internal error has occurred. Please try your query again at a later time.  

status code: 500 root.rds-virginia.db.db_option_group: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence
```

How to resolve or work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dummy db option group (even though we don't need it for this use case) seems to work around this issue:

```
resource "aws_db_option_group" "some-option-group" {
  name                     = "dummy-mysql-option-group"
  option_group_description = "Dummy Mysql option group"
  engine_name              = "mysql"
  major_engine_version     = "5.7"
}
```

Terraform db option group docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_option_group.html